# How to create custom validation for email conformation in the TYPO3 powermail extension?

Tags: validation, typo3, fluid, parsley.js, powermail

I want to implement email conformation field just like password conformation. for ex: user add email address in the first field and conform with other field. both must be same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The manual gives some helpful examples.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/WriteOwnValidators/Index.html

There are three subpages where you can find examples how to create:
- a new validation type for input fields
- a global serverside validator
- a global clientside validator

Answer (score 2):

You can use below typoscript for custome powermail validation. Using `powermailextended` extension.

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
     settings.setup {
             validation {
                     customValidation {
                             100 = In2code\Powermailextended\Domain\Validator\your_php_file_name
                     }
             }
     }
     _LOCAL_LANG.default.validationerror_validation.100 = Please add a ZIP with 8 begginning
}
```